# onclick not working in webkit or mozilla when z-index is negative value

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, z-index

I have the following div set which only works in IE9. On Moz and Webkit the onclick will not fire. If I chaneg the z-index to 0, the onclick works, but I have visibility issues with other elements in the site. Is there a way to get onclick to fire with negative z-indices?

```
<div id="adbg" style="margin: 0pt auto; height: 1000px; width: 100%; position: fixed; cursor: pointer; z-index: -1;">
<div OnClick="window.open('/bgClicks/2');" style="background: #fff url('http://www.example.com/img/bg/w_1.jpg') no-repeat center top fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0pt auto; cursor: pointer;"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
```

Comment: Please provide a demo. But, my guess is that if you have a negative `z-index` and onclick isn't working, then it might be some transparent element covering your clickable things.

Comment: 'Visibility issues' sound like the element is on top of other elements. Making the z-index negative causes the element to drop below the other elements, causing those other elements to capture the click event.

Comment: If possible, changing all the z-index values to positives usually gives better results.

Comment: Working in IE9 is by coincidence. Moz and Webkit here do the correct (expected) behaviour. MS is the oddball out and is doing the wrong thing. ProTip: If IE is the only one to get it right... it's probably still wrong.

Comment: Your pasted code works, it must be because of other components in your page. A link to your site if it's live **might** be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Having a z-index of `-` here is definitely the problem. What is happening in Moz/Webkit is the outcome to be expected, you must have an invisible/transparent laying over the object that is picking up the click, thus not letting it go through to the actual link.

There are several things you can do..
1) Find the object that is over-lying it (Pretty easy in Chrome, just right click - inspect element, and usually the direct element under the mouse will be automatically highlighted in the inspector. Then for this element give a css rule of:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

This allows the click to register through it and to the object below.
Please note [browser support](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events) for this isn't great, so I'd suggest another solution:

2) Restructure your code so that you don't run into this problem, in the logical world why would you have anything over the top of a link anyway, it's down to poor structuring really, re-think your margins/paddings, or make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can have a better look :).